# Can we draw google chart with two y-axis one with top and other with bottom, with same x-axis?

Tags: charts, angular, google-visualization, angular-chart

I need to use google chart with two y-axis and one x-axis, like (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirometry#/media/File:Flow-volume-loop.svg). Does google chart support this type of graph?

Comment: Refer this link - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

Comment: Your picture actually only has one y-axis, but I think the special thing about that chart is that the x-axis labels appear inside the chart area at the y=0 line. A chart with "two y-axes" usually has two different scales, to compare relations that either have very different ranges of numbers (units sold and units in stock) or entirely different units of measure (rainfall vs. river flow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to create a graph as referenced by the link
use a single y-axis, with negative values for the bottom portion

then use object notation to set both the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)
`{v: -8, f: '8'}`

then use the same notation for the y-axis tick marks (`ticks:`)

the chart will display the formatted value on the axis as well as tooltips

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X', 'Y'],
      [1.5,  8],
      [2.5,  4],
      [3.5,  1],
      [1.5, {v: -8, f: '8'}],
      [2.5, {v: -4, f: '4'}],
      [3.5, {v: -1, f: '1'}],
    ]);

    var ticksX = [0, 2, 4, 6];
    var ticksY = [{v: -10, f: '10'}, {v: -8, f: '8'}, {v: -6, f: '6'}, {v: -4, f: '4'}, {v: -2, f: '2'}, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        title: 'h axis',
        ticks: ticksX
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'v axis',
        ticks: ticksY,
        viewWindow: {
          min: -10,
          max: 10
        }
      },
      height: 600,
      width: 600,
      chartArea: {
        height: '75%',
        width: '75%'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: yes great. I tried this out in jsfiddle it is working. thanks